# How to hide items of a combobox in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, combobox, visibility

Is there a way to hide items of a combobox in WPF?
In my usercontrol there is a ListBox with checkbox-items bound to an ObservableCollection and a datagrid with a combobox.

```
<ListBox x:Name="AvailableAttributes" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" SelectionMode="Single" >
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=OneWay}"/>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>

    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>

... 

<DataGrid Name="datagrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" />
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn 
                SelectedValueBinding="{Binding CBID}" 
                DisplayMemberPath="Name" 
                SelectedValuePath="ID">

                <DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                        <Setter Property="ItemsSource" 
                            Value="{Binding Path=CBItems, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" />
                    </Style>
                </DataGridComboBoxColumn.ElementStyle>
                <DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
                        <Setter Property="ItemsSource" 
                            Value="{Binding Path=CBItems, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" />
                    </Style>
                </DataGridComboBoxColumn.EditingElementStyle>
            </DataGridComboBoxColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

I used [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5409259/binding-itemssource-of-a-comboboxcolumn-in-wpf-datagrid) to manage the combobox items and added the property 'IsSelected'

```
public class GridItem
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int CBID { get; set; }
}

public class CBItem
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to use the 'IsSelected' property to hide/show the item in the combobox. Can someone tell me how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pretty simple: Just give the combobox items a style with a trigger that sets `ComboBoxItem.Visibility` according to the value of `IsSelected` on the `ComboBoxItem`'s `DataContext`:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ComboBox}}">
    <Setter Property="ItemsSource" 
        Value="{Binding Path=CBItems, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" />
    <Setter Property="ItemContainerStyle">
        <Setter.Value>
            <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type ComboBoxItem}}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected}" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

If you might ever be updating the value of `IsSelected` on any of these items after the ComboBoxes are loaded in the grid, you will need to [implement INotifyPropertyChanged](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29979567/424129) on `CBItem` so that the UI will reflect the change.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is awesome :)

Comment: Also add `<Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False" />` otherwise users can select the collapsed item by arrow key

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna show a specific property and filter out items according to another property value you should use `ItemTemplate` and `ItemContainerStyle` together.
In this example `ItemSource` has set to an `ObservableCollection` type property which is part of another Combobox `ItemSource`

```
  <ComboBox x:Name="combo2" ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItem.Devices,ElementName=combo1}">
     <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
           <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
      </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
      <ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
         <Style TargetType="ComboBoxItem">
            <Style.Triggers>
               <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DeviceId}" Value="125">
                  <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"></Setter>
               </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
         </Style>
      </ComboBox.ItemContainerStyle>
 </ComboBox>
```